# easyUI datagrid pagination displaying Nan of nan items

Tags: php, codeigniter, datagrid, pagination, jquery-easyui

Im doing an application with code igniter and easyui datagrid, I set

pagination:true

but the next and back button aren't working and the pagination info says

> Displaying 1 to NaN of NaN items

I've been googling around but still no luck.

here is my JS:

```
var tablegrid = $('#datagrid');
var cols = [[
            {field:'referal',title:'Referal',align:'center'},
            {field:'firstName',title:'First Name',align:'center'},
            ....
    ]];
tablegrid.datagrid({
    title: "Register a Friend",
    url: base_url + 'notification/get_friend_notification',
    columns: cols,
    pagination: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    singleSelect: true
});
```

and here is my controller

```
    $results["rows"] = $this->mnotification->get_friend_list();
    echo json_encode($results);
```

The model:

```
public function get_friend_list() {
$params = $this->input->post();
$offset = $params['rows'] * $params['page']; 
$sql = $this->db->query(/* sql query.. */);
return $sql->result();
}
```

Comment: Anyone please? can you help me on this? i can send you screenshots if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my trusty colleague he helped me find for an answer. What I did was

1. I retained the js as it is.
2. modified my controller a bit, instead of

   ```php
   $results["rows"] = $this->mnotification->get_friend_list();
   ```

   I modified it into a variable that accepts an array from the model:

   ```php
   $results = $this->mnotification->get_friend_list();
   ```
3. the mnotification model (very important), this is where I passed the result as an array

   ```php
   public function get_friend_list() {
   $result = array();

   $params = $this->input->post();

   $offset = $params['rows'] *( $params['page'] - 1);

   $query = "SELECT * FROM ..."; // sql statement

   // created index total for the total number of fetched data.
   $result['total'] = $this->db->query($query)->num_rows; 

   //appended limit and offset on the query string.
   $query .= " LIMIT {$params['rows']} OFFSET {$offset}";

   // pass all the result in index total. 
   $result['rows'] = $this->db->query($query)->result(); 

   }
   ```

I hope it helps!